# In-app Billing design - How to give the user free items on first install

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want to implement in-app billing for my application where users can purchase coins. However I want the users to get some free coins when they first try the game. How do I go about implementing this?

If I just store it in the app settings, they can just keep re-installing the game and getting the free coins again. And the SD card is not secure enough, I don't want people tampering with it easily.

I hope this isn't a duplicate but I looked around and couldn't find anything in the docs. Iv'e seen a few suggestions but they all include using your own server, which I do not want to do.

Comment: Keep a record of the user's account on your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App settings are removed when the app is uninstalled, so unless they backup the app settings they will lose progress every time they "reinstall". And if they do backup the app settings, then restoring them would actually restore your setting indicating that they have already received their coins :) I don't see why this wouldn't work as a quick solution.

The only really secure way would be to do it on a server which you control, but if you do not have access to that, then doing it in the app settings should work - some people might get around it, but they will get around pretty much anything and it is not worth the energy trying to prevent that.

As an additional check you could also only award the coins if the user has none (which I am assuming will be the case on an initial install) - that way they can't keep getting coins by clearing your setting (if they are rooted).